# Symmetry transformation from Lectures on Quantum Mechanics by Steven Weinberg

Tags: quantum-mechanics, symmetry

Here is an excerpt from the book "Lectures on Quantum Mechanics by Steven Weinberg". It says,

> A symmetry principle is a statement that, when we change our point of view in certain ways, the laws of nature do not change. For instance, **moving or rotating our laboratory** should not change the laws of nature observed in the laboratory. Such special ways of changing our point of view are called symmetry transformations. This deﬁnition does not mean that a symmetry transformation
> does not change physical states, but only that the new states after a symmetry transformation will be observed to satisfy the same laws of nature as the old states.

What does Weinberg mean by "moving or rotating our laboratory"?

**CASE - I** Does he mean rotating the laboratory in relation to the system i.e., rotating the environment of the system while leaving the system untouched?

**CASE - II** Does he mean rotating the laboratory together with the system so that there is no relative change between the system and its environment?

If anyone can help me understand this, I will very much appreciate it. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He means this:

1. Imagine the front door to the lab (with your test apparatus bolted to a bench in it) faces the south. You pick up the entire lab with the bench inside and turn it so the front door now faces north, thereby rotating the apparatus by 180 degrees.  You'll get the same test results as you did before rotating the apparatus.
2. Imagine your lab building sits at the southeast corner of First and A streets. You pick up the entire lab and move it to the northwest corner of First and A. You'll get the same test results as you did before moving the lab.

Comment: So it is case - II of my question.

Comment: @Solidification Just to emphasize a point that's implicit in this answer -- you need to transform *everything* relevant for the physics to see that there is a symmetry. So if you were doing an experiment that was sensitive to the Earth's gravitational field, and if you did a rotation of the lab in the $xz$ plane, where $z$ is the vertical direction, you would *also* need to rotate *the Earth* in order to see the rotational symmetry in this plane.